# Meeting up at Scrum Gathering

Tags: discussion

I hope it's ok to post this here - I'll happily remove it if not. It's great being part of this StackExchange community with you all. I was wondering if anyone else was going to Scrum Gathering April and would want to meet up while we're there.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it seems there's [3 locations](https://www.scrumalliance.org/courses-events/events/global-gatherings/2016) where there'll be a Scrum Gathering in 2016. Which one are you referring you to? I won't be in any of them... but being more specific, you might have more answers :)

Comment: Fair point - I was thinking of Orlando Apr 18 - 20 (https://www.scrumalliance.org/courses-events/events/global-gatherings/2016/orlando-2016)